# Exclude Multiple Different Cells When Importing Data

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, formula

I am trying to `filter(query())` some specific columns into a spreadsheet where I do some automatic calculations. However, there are 8 or so *specific* strings that I don't need and clutter the calculations page. I have a list of these strings that I don't need but I can't seem to EXCLUDE these strings from the `filter(query())` without creating a 15 line block of text.

What I've Tried:

`=FILTER(QUERY(A:C,"select A,C"),QUERY(A:C,"select A")<>D2,D3,D4,D5)`

`=FILTER(QUERY(A:C,"select A, C"),QUERY(A:C,"select A")<>{D2,D3,D4,D5})` - I have also tried this one joining the text w/ a "," so that there is one value

`=FILTER(QUERY(A:C,"select A, C"),QUERY(A:C,"select A")<>D2)` - What is silly is THIS ONE VALUE works, but I cant add multiple values without adding 7 more conditions to the filter which would exclude the values that I need excluded, but I would have to change the formula manually and it would be monstrous when I keep adding strings to remove.

The goal is to be able to be able to add another string to a separate cell and have that be excluded as well.

Here is the google sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1u-Po1Oae4MTYU10o_-1Yu0s9Ras9JUn4-SFzTkmMldI/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Suggestion

Perhaps you can try using `REGEXMATCH` so you could add multiple words to be matched but in the reverse way *(via placing the `REGEXMATCH` in a `NOT` function)* to `FILTER` your data more efficiently as seen below:

```
=FILTER(QUERY(Sheet1!A:C,"select A, C"),NOT(REGEXMATCH(Sheet1!A:A,"Value 7|Value 3|Value 10|Value 8")))
```

Alternatively, you could also reference the range of cells you want to exclude in the `REGEXMATCH` via `JOIN` function like:

```
=FILTER(QUERY(Sheet1!A:C,"select A, C"),NOT(REGEXMATCH(Sheet1!A:A,JOIN("|",D2:D5))))
```

***[UPDATE]***

If you're using an `IMPORTRANGE` in your actual sheet formula, then you would need to structure it like this sample. The `REGEXMATCH` formula also contains a range:

```
=FILTER(QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/XXXXXX","Sheet1!A:C"),"select Col1, Col3"),NOT(REGEXMATCH(QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/XXXXXX","Sheet1!A:C"),"select Col1"),"Value 7|Value 3|Value 10|Value 8")))
```

### Demo

- *Sample Test*

[image]

- *The referenced Sheet 1*

[image]

### References

- [REGEXMATCH](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098292)
- [NOT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093305)
- [JOIN](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094077)

Comment: There must be something wrong with either my sheet, or importrange because it works just fine on the test sheet I made and you did, but on the sheet I am using and with the specific data I am using (an address)- it doesn't work...
It doesn't provide an error, it is almost like it is sees the NOT(REGEXMATCH() value and doesn't see that it matches the value I am inputting even when I copy paste the single value...
Thanks for your help- this is the answer- but for some reason it isn't working...

Comment: I see. If you're using `IMPORTRANGE`, then I suppose you need to also reference the range in the `REGEXMATCH` function, I have updated my answer for more context.

Comment: Thanks! Yeah I am quite familiar w/ 'IMPORTRANGE', this is what I have and it just doesn't work with the data I am using, don't worry about it, I'll live.
`=FILTER(QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("xxxxxxxxxxxxx","Sheet1!C:H"),"select Col1, Col6"),NOT(REGEXMATCH(query(IMPORTRANGE("xxxx","Sheet1!C:H"),"select Col1"),"123 S Test Street Ave (Lot 1 Blk 2)"))`
Thanks for the answer update! I appreciate it @SputnikDrunk2